# Last command not showing output for some users. How can I check for tampering?

Tags: linux, security

We have a server, and I tried to check the output of the `last` command.

For most users in the system the last command is working.

When it comes to root, or to another user the output of `last` is as follows:

`wtmp begins Fri Dec  9 07:14:25 2017`

I have tried logging in and logging out of all users to see what is being captured, and this is still the output.

I am trying to understand if someone has modified the log, or if this is normal?

Comment: How are those users logging in?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas using SSH

Comment: That they are logging in as root using SSH seems unlikely, given how hard operating systems people have pushed for this _not_ to be possible in the default configuration over the past few years.  Are they _really_ logging in as root?  Or are you conflating this with logging in as another user _and then adding root privileges in the login session_ with the `su` command?

Answer (score 4):

The information displayed by the `last` command is stored in the `wtmp` file, which is normally located at `/var/log/wtmp`.

Since this file will grow without any upper limit while the system is being used, the default configuration for most Linux distributions will implement an automated log rotation procedure for this file.

The default rotation for `/var/log/wtmp` might be weekly or monthly. Usually some number of old versions of the file are kept as `/var/log/wtmp.1`, `/var/log/wtmp.2` etc. In some distributions, a datestamp is used instead of an increasing number.

If you need `last` output from a previous log rotation cycle, use the `-f` option to point the `last` command to an older version of the wtmp file. For example:

```
last -f /var/log/wtmp.1
```

If you want to change the log rotation cycle of the wtmp file, or tell the system to keep a larger number of previous versions, look into files `/etc/logrotate.conf` and `/etc/logrotate.d/*` - these are where log rotation procedures are typically defined.

Answer (score 0):

Same on my (Ubuntu) system which I (presumptuously?) consider untampered. If the timestamp is the last time you booted the system this can be normal. This can be distro-dependent (on Ubuntu (workstation) root never logs in...).

Not all system-altering actions result in a entry in wtmp/last, you can access files via SFTP if there is an SSH access, and these connections are tracked by /var/log/auth.log